# Issue with setting up jest mock

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, testing, jestjs, cypress

I have the following function that is used within cypress tests for which I want to do unit testing (filterTests.js):

```
const filterTests = (definedTags, runTest) => {
  console.log(`Cypress tags: ${definedTags}`);
  let isFound = true;
  
  const includeTag = Cypress.env('INCLUDETAG');
  const excludeTag = Cypress.env('EXCLUDETAG');
  
  if (includeTag) {
    isFound = definedTags.includes(includeTag);
  }

  if (excludeTag) {
    isFound = ! definedTags.includes(excludeTag);
  }

  if (isFound) {
    runTest();
  }
};

export default filterTests;
```

A test double for Cypress.env needs to be created. I'm not sure if this would technically be considered a stub, mock, fake, dummy, etc..., but the philosophical discussion isn't the focus right now. It looks like in the Cypress world, everything is lumped together under 'mock'.

I started down the path of something like this in the Jest test file:

```
import filterTests from '../../cypress/support/filterTests';

describe('Something', () => {
  jest.mock('Cypress', () => ({
      env: {
        INCLUDETAG: 'jenkins1'
      }
  }));


  it('Something else ', (done) => {
    const tempFunc = () => {
      console.log('here a');
      done();
    };

    filterTests(tag, tempFunc);
  });
});
```

But for that I get the error message:

```
    Cannot find module 'Cypress' from 'spec/cypress/filterTestsSO2.test.js'

      2 |
      3 | describe('Something', () => {
    > 4 |   jest.mock('Cypress', () => ({
        |        ^
      5 |       env: {
      6 |         INCLUDETAG: 'jenkins1'
      7 |       }
```

I believe what is complicating this situation is that Cypress is not explicitly imported in filterTests.js

Comment: What are you trying to mock, the `Cypress.env(...)` call? From what I know Jest stubs `require()` to do it's mocking, but you don't ever import of require Cypress - it's loaded on the global before the tests start running.

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to swap out Cypress.env. And what you mention about require (and import as well) appears to be the crux of the issue that I'm running into: in that the way the fitlerTests.js code works in the context of Cypress, there is no explicit require/import statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might just want to set the env value at the top of the test

```js
describe('Something', () => {

  Cypress.env(INCLUDETAG, 'jenkins1')

  it('Something else ', (done) => {
    const tempFunc = () => {
      console.log('here a');
      done();
    };

    filterTests(tag, tempFunc);  // this function will read the env set above
  })
})
```

Further info - Cypress has a `cy.spy()` which wraps a method and records it's calls but otherwise leaves it's result the same.

Also `cy.stub()` which records calls but also provides a fake result.

---

**Jest globals**

If you are running the test in Jest, then the Cypress global should be able to be mocked simply by setting it up

```js
global.Cypress = {
  env: () => 'jenkins1'  // or more complicated fn as test requires
}
```

Note I expect this will only work with simple cases. Cypress wraps jQuery, Chai and Mocha so they behave slightly differently when a Cypress test runs. If the function you test uses any of those features, even implicitly (like command retry), then Jest will not reproduce the right environment.

My recommendation, test Cypress with Cypress.

Comment: In your suggestion, the line Cypress.env(INCLUDETAG, 'jenkins') is going to fail because neither Cypress or Cypress.env have been set. And also even they did get set, they're not going to be available inside of filterTests.js

Comment: No, sorry that's totally incorrect. When you start a Cypress test it gives you a `Cypress` object which has a method `env()` which can either get or set a variable. You can check it out in the docs.

Comment: I mean, just try it - it works (as long as you are running the Cypress runner). If you're trying to do this inside the Jest runner, well I'm not sure there's any point in setting Cypress values inside a Jest test.

Comment: There's some confusion. Yes, of course Cypress is available inside of a straight forward cypress test. However I'm trying to use Jest to test some custom logic I wrote for Cypress tests. The Cypress object is not automatically available in Jest, and is also not automatically available in filterTests.js when being tested through Jest.

Comment: Are you running that code you provided through Cypress or Jest?

Comment: Ok, it turns out Cypress can be mocked off of global. I had tried testing that before and it wasn't working, but I must have made a mistake. I went back and tried it again, and now it's working for me. Thanks for your assistance!

Comment: Regarding the recommendation of using Cypress for Cypress, my initial instinct was to use Jest for unit testing (which is the type of test in this specific case) and have functional tests run through Cypress. I was able to come up with a way to meet that requirement in this particular situation, but going forward I will probably have to be flexible in terms of following that rule.